# Install the tower RPM task failed

Tags: linux, ansible, openshift, redhat, ansible-tower

Tried running the setup.sh file for installing ansbile tower.
But the script keeps failing at install the tower RPM task.
ansible version=2.8

> TASK [packages_el : Install the Tower RPM.]
>
> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "changes":
> {"installed": ["ansible-tower == 3.5.0"], "updated": []}, "msg":
> "Repository 'extras' is missing name in configuration, using
> id\nRepository 'new_extras' is missing name in configuration, using
> id\nRepository 'dvd' is missing name in configuration, using
> id\nError: Package: ansible-tower-venv-tower-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64
> (ansible-tower)\n           Requires: rh-python36-python\nError:
> Package: ansible-tower-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64 (ansible-tower)\n
> Requires: rh-python36-runtime\n", "rc": 1, "results": ["Loaded
> plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-\n
> : manager\nThis system is not registered with an entitlement server.
> You can use subscription-manager to register.\nResolving
> Dependencies\n--> Running transaction check\n---> Package
> ansible-tower.x86_64 0:3.5.0-1.el7at will be installed\n--> Processing
> Dependency: ansible-tower-ui = 3.5.0-1.el7at for package:
> ansible-tower-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> ansible-tower-server = 3.5.0-1.el7at for package:
> ansible-tower-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> rh-python36-runtime for package:
> ansible-tower-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n--> Running transaction
> check\n---> Package ansible-tower.x86_64 0:3.5.0-1.el7at will be
> installed\n--> Processing Dependency: rh-python36-runtime for package:
> ansible-tower-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n---> Package
> ansible-tower-server.x86_64 0:3.5.0-1.el7at will be installed\n-->
> Processing Dependency: ansible-tower-venv-tower = 3.5.0-1.el7at for
> package: ansible-tower-server-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n--> Processing
> Dependency: ansible-tower-venv-ansible = 3.5.0-1.el7at for package:
> ansible-tower-server-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> supervisor >= 3.0 for package:
> ansible-tower-server-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> bubblewrap >= 0.1.2 for package:
> ansible-tower-server-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> subversion for package: ansible-tower-server-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n-->
> Processing Dependency: rabbitmq-server for package:
> ansible-tower-server-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> postgresql96 for package:
> ansible-tower-server-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> mercurial for package: ansible-tower-server-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n-->
> Processing Dependency: memcached for package:
> ansible-tower-server-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n---> Package
> ansible-tower-ui.x86_64 0:3.5.0-1.el7at will be installed\n--> Running
> transaction check\n---> Package ansible-tower.x86_64 0:3.5.0-1.el7at
> will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: rh-python36-runtime for
> package: ansible-tower-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n---> Package
> ansible-tower-venv-ansible.x86_64 0:3.5.0-1.el7at will be
> installed\n--> Processing Dependency: python-virtualenv for package:
> ansible-tower-venv-ansible-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n---> Package
> ansible-tower-venv-tower.x86_64 0:3.5.0-1.el7at will be installed\n-->
> Processing Dependency: rh-python36-python for package:
> ansible-tower-venv-tower-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n---> Package
> bubblewrap.x86_64 0:0.3.3-2.el7at will be installed\n---> Package
> memcached.x86_64 0:1.4.15-10.el7_3.1 will be installed\n---> Package
> mercurial.x86_64 0:2.6.2-8.el7_4 will be installed\n---> Package
> postgresql96.x86_64 0:9.6.6-1PGDG.el7 will be installed\n-->
> Processing Dependency: postgresql96-libs(x86-64) = 9.6.6-1PGDG.el7 for
> package: postgresql96-9.6.6-1PGDG.el7.x86_64\n---> Package
> rabbitmq-server.noarch 0:3.7.4-2.el7at will be installed\n-->
> Processing Dependency: erlang >= 19.3 for package:
> rabbitmq-server-3.7.4-2.el7at.noarch\n---> Package subversion.x86_64
> 0:1.7.14-14.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency:
> subversion-libs(x86-64) = 1.7.14-14.el7 for package:
> subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> libsvn_client-1.so.0()(64bit) for package:
> subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> libsvn_delta-1.so.0()(64bit) for package:
> subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> libsvn_diff-1.so.0()(64bit) for package:
> subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> libsvn_fs-1.so.0()(64bit) for package:
> subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> libsvn_fs_base-1.so.0()(64bit) for package:
> subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> libsvn_fs_fs-1.so.0()(64bit) for package:
> subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> libsvn_fs_util-1.so.0()(64bit) for package:
> subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> libsvn_ra-1.so.0()(64bit) for package:
> subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> libsvn_ra_local-1.so.0()(64bit) for package:
> subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> libsvn_ra_neon-1.so.0()(64bit) for package:
> subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> libsvn_ra_svn-1.so.0()(64bit) for package:
> subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> libsvn_repos-1.so.0()(64bit) for package:
> subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> libsvn_subr-1.so.0()(64bit) for package:
> subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64\n--> Processing Dependency:
> libsvn_wc-1.so.0()(64bit) for package:
> subversion-1.7.14-14.el7.x86_64\n---> Package supervisor.noarch
> 0:3.1.4-1.el7 will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency:
> python-meld3 >= 0.6.5 for package: supervisor-3.1.4-1.el7.noarch\n-->
> Running transaction check\n---> Package ansible-tower.x86_64
> 0:3.5.0-1.el7at will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency:
> rh-python36-runtime for package:
> ansible-tower-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n---> Package
> ansible-tower-venv-tower.x86_64 0:3.5.0-1.el7at will be installed\n-->
> Processing Dependency: rh-python36-python for package:
> ansible-tower-venv-tower-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n---> Package
> erlang.x86_64 0:20.3.8.9-3.el7at will be installed\n---> Package
> postgresql96-libs.x86_64 0:9.6.6-1PGDG.el7 will be installed\n--->
> Package python-meld3.x86_64 0:0.6.10-1.el7 will be installed\n--->
> Package python-virtualenv.noarch 0:15.1.0-2.el7 will be installed\n-->
> Processing Dependency: python2-devel for package:
> python-virtualenv-15.1.0-2.el7.noarch\n---> Package
> subversion-libs.x86_64 0:1.7.14-14.el7 will be installed\n--> Running
> transaction check\n---> Package ansible-tower.x86_64 0:3.5.0-1.el7at
> will be installed\n--> Processing Dependency: rh-python36-runtime for
> package: ansible-tower-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n---> Package
> ansible-tower-venv-tower.x86_64 0:3.5.0-1.el7at will be installed\n-->
> Processing Dependency: rh-python36-python for package:
> ansible-tower-venv-tower-3.5.0-1.el7at.x86_64\n---> Package
> python-devel.x86_64 0:2.7.5-68.el7 will be installed\n--> Finished
> Dependency Resolution\n You could try using --skip-broken to work
> around the problem\n You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles
> --nodigest\n"]}

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the key (from your error above): "This system is not registered with an entitlement server. You can use subscription-manager to register"

Also, does this server have Internet-connectivity to reach the RPM repositories? I know I have tried to upgrade the Ansible Tower bundle from a 'secured' server (no internet access), and it fails because it can't resolve package dependencies.

This blog post talks about how to retrieve all the necessary dependencies to make a completely standalone bundle:  https://www.ansiblejunky.com/blog/create-complete-offline-ansible-tower-bundle/  (note, I have not tried this method, but it looks solid).